# Compute Engine in Google Cloud

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, disk

I am trying to install `tensorflow` after installing **anaconda** in the home directory. It is giving disk storage space issue. I increased the disc storage to `30 GB` and problem remains same. I am not able to change storage space allocation to different drive. With `df` command it is showing below:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none             30G   23G  5.5G  81% /
tmpfs           853M     0  853M   0% /dev
tmpfs           853M     0  853M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1       4.8G  4.4G  164M  97% /home
/dev/sda1        30G   23G  5.5G  81% /etc/ssh/keys
tmpfs           171M  636K  170M   1% /google/host/var/run
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /google/host/var/run/lock
tmpfs           341M  1.2M  340M   1% /google/host/var/run/shm
tmpfs           853M     0  853M   0% /run/google/devshell
```

I am not sure why below space is occupied.

**"/dev/sda1        30G   23G  5.5G  81% /etc/ssh/keys"**

is using `23 GB`.

It is giving storage space during installation. Request you to suggest how make the space free and available as I have not installed any other application.

Comment: I created a new VM instance with a 30 GB boot disk and installed Anaconda to try and reproduce the issue. I ran the "df" command and did not get the same results. Were you using a new VM instance for this or was it already running when you installed Anaconda? There should not be anything stored in /etc/ssh/keys on a newly created VM instance.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it should not happen, see if restart works. BTW how much was the size before?